Not able to catch this warning: Telegram is having internal issues TimeoutError
I’m developing an async Telegram bot using asyncio, and I’ve implemented retry logic for my message_listener function to handle errors like TimeoutError. My code attempts to catch all exceptions with except Exception as e to ensure the listener restarts after any error. However, when a TimeoutError  occurs, the task stops completely without triggering the except block or retrying, even though my heartbeat task continues running.
Example log:
2024-11-13 22:10:05,488:WARNING:Telegram is having internal issues TimeoutError: Timeout while fetching data (caused by GetHistoryRequest)

I suspect that the task may be cancelled silently or that the exception is not propagating back to my try-except block.
Key Code:
async def message_listener():
    try:
        while True:
            message = await client.get_messages(chat, limit=1)
            # Process message
    except Exception as e:
        # General error handling and retry


try:
        await asyncio.gather(
            reading_telegram.message_listener(),
            monitoring_status.send_heartbeat()
    )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(f"An error occurred on reading_relegram.py: {e}")


Question: How can I ensure message_listener restarts reliably if it encounters TimeoutError or stops silently? Why is none of my exceptions catching this? Is this the expected result for telethon?
